# Unable to charge HP NoteBook 840 G4 laptop while being overseas

Tags: electronic-items, power

I work for a software company in the US. I decided to take some vacation time and fly back home (to one of the former Soviet countries). My manager asked me to grab a work laptop with me to perform some tasks remotely.

I remember I was going home several years ago and got my personal laptop that time, and a simple adapter from US type outlets to European type (I guess they call it Type C or Type F). It was more than enough to use it.

However, this time I'm having a really hard time to even launch my work laptop. Plugging in the power cord does nothing (the charge icon is not flashing, pressing the power button does nothing). I used a voltage checker and it showed normal voltage at the end of the cord, so the next suspicion I guess is either the battery has died, or I need some really special adapter to make this HP laptop work.

Has anyone had this problem before specifically with HP brand? Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction are higly appreciated. Thanks a lot people!

[image: Adapter the one I used with my personal laptop several years ago]

[image: Adapter the one I used with my personal laptop several years ago]

[image: Adapter the one I used with my personal laptop several years ago]

Comment: Did you ensure that your US laptop’s adapter can handle 240 V instead of the typical US 120V ?

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk I added screenshots for clarifications. The white adapter is the one I used several years ago and it was working perfectly fine with my personal laptop. The third image is the black box in the middle of my power cord where it can be seen that power cord accepts range of inputs

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk It's really hard to imagine anybody making a laptop power adaptor that would only work in North America.

Comment: Maybe the white adaptor you are using is broken. Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Maybe your laptop is sending you a message that you are on vacations ?

Comment: Did you push the adapter all the way into the spring-loaded European outlet, or just enough so that the two pins rattle loosely?

Comment: Those multi-country adapters are non-standard and really don't meet safety standards. You should try getting the correct cable from the wall to the brick and try that. At minimum, try plugging some other appliance into the white adapter.

Comment: What do you mean by "A voltage checker device"?

Comment: Plug **something else** right into the adapter (like a lamp, for example) and make sure that item works. It should accept the local plugs as well as your US style. This is a better check than using a test lamp or multimeter because it can't be fooled by capacitive coupling etc. If it doesn't then either the adapter or the wall socket power is bad.

Comment: The adapter works perfectly fine, I can charge my “bought in America” iPhone with no problem

Comment: I'm going to guess your 'brick' has died. If you really want to work, I'd look for a replacement brick, at least to test the hypothesis. I've never had a problem with the universal adapters.

Comment: Is it normal for US employers to have employees working while on holiday?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: I'd like to point out that a cursory Google search for "hp elitebook 840 g4 not charging" shows that many other users are having the same issue as you, so it really seems like a poorly timed hardware failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks a lot people for your time and patience and advice. All of you really tried to help me resolve my problem.

This is incredibly ridiculous, but the problem was not in the cord or adapter or any kind of hardware. I called HP support center to figure what might have gone wrong. It seems like I shut down the laptop before my flight, but what (probably) happened is the laptop didn't shut down correctly, rather went to hibernate mode.

In this case (according to the HP support guy), the laptop won't charge at all (WHAT???) from any sort of cord / wires / chargers. In order to resolve this

> the user has to hold the power button on the laptop for 10 seconds.

Before he/she sees some light flashing on the keyboard then release this power button.

What is this: security feature? Power saving feature? Bug in the software? God knows! And I've been struggling with it several days.

Good thing that I didn't decide to replace the battery, for which in this specific HP model I would have to take the bottom cover out in order to get to the battery. And in our company this is against the policy to dig inside assigned hardware (sealed), which might get us punished even with employee discharge :-)

Comment: I have never heard of this hibernate thing!  Amazing!  But HP has been making hardware broken in odd ways for years and years.  Their original IBM PC AT clone beeped the PC speaker - in the BIOS where you couldn't change it - whenever it switched from extended mode to real mode.  They thought it was a good idea I guess but that meant if you ran a RAM disk or anything else in extended memory your speaker was beeping one solid tone all the time - until you gave up and cut the wires to it.

Answer (score 24):

There's nothing in your pictures that indicates that they *shouldn't* work on a European grid. I think you need to treat this exactly like any other instance of: **My laptop and/or its power brick died unexpectedly while I'm traveling**.

Assuming your employer is not so large that they have an office (with local IT support) near you, typically the plan would be something like:

1. Call HP in the country you're in and get the address of resellers or repair centres close to you who might be able to sell you a new (local) power brick.
2. Call your boss and get his/her blessing to buy that and expense it later. (Also get them to find out if your company has any worldwide service agreements that cover the laptop).
3. When you're there, ask politely if you can plug your laptop into one of their supplies for a minute or two, to make sure it is the power brick rather than the laptop that's dead.
4. If it's the laptop, then you're in greater trouble.

Comment: If it were me, I would just report to IT support "my laptop is dead" and be done with it. The OP is on vacation, the fact that he agreed to perform his own work while on vacation is one thing, but he really shouldn't need to do the IT department's work on top of that. It's *their* job to provide him with a laptop and charger that works in the destination country. It's *their* problem how they manage to do that: FedEx him a new laptop, send an employee halfway across the world to fix the laptop, have the laptop picked up at the hotel by a local HP support technician, …

Answer (score 12):

Try a power outlet *outside* your room/hotel.

It is known that in several countries, namely Italy, the electric outlets in many famly/small chains hotels are only good enough to drive electric shavers or similar devices on purpose.

Whilst it does not appear your case, it could also happen all your room outlets are broken. It already happened to me twice.

Comment: Those outlets are usually clearly marked as being razor-only, but the idea of trying another outlet is a sound one.  It's possible the outlet tried is defective, or is operated by an on/off switch that was powered off.

Comment: Those outlets in Italy and Eastern countries are not marked as razor only and often foreigns are left wondering why they do not work

Comment: I would also try another plug adapter. Sometimes they're poorly made and the electrical connection is loose.

Comment: They're not always marked razor-only, and some (many?) standard outlets are controlled by a switch - and that switch is not always directly next to the outlet!  (And frequently the switches are upside-down w.r.t. the US standard!)

Comment: A possibility is to check in the room for the electric outlet that powers the TV and plug the adapter in it; without doubt it will provide more power than the necessary to power an electric shaver.

Comment: The TV seems a good idea. In the past I used the fridge outlet, but with more and more smart fridges, it might not be the brightest of the actions nowadays